# Retrieve data from Firebase and send an email

Tags: email, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know if there is some service to do what I want to do. The point is that I have an app connected to Firebase (I don't have backend) and I want to automatize some emails. Every day I want to send an email with some of the records stored in Firebase. I don't want to code with node or whatever, so I am looking something like Zapier (I have taken a look at it, and I think it's not possible to do this). I have taken a look at Cloud Functions for Firebase but seems that the function is a trigger, and I need something like a daily job. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you may not like the idea of using Node.js, Cloud Functions for Firebase would be a way to build this functionality with relatively little code. You can find out how to send an email [in this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation) and see how to set up a cron job [in this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron).

Comment: I think that the second sample fits with what I want to do. I will take a look at the sample. Thanks!